# SendMessage function only send first character of the message fromm VC++ app to reciever (Delphi App)?

Tags: delphi, visual-c++, sendmessage

SendMessage only send first charter of the message VC++, can you help?
Only first charter is recieved.

Actually here is my full sender app code (VC++)

```c
   // notification->FileName is UCHAR[255]

        HWND app = FindWindow(NULL,TEXT("Message Receiver"));
        COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
    cds.dwData = 0; // can be anything
    cds.cbData = sizeof(notification->FileName) - sizeof(UCHAR);
    cds.lpData = (void*)notification->FileName;
     SendMessageA(app, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)app, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

My reciever code (Delphi)

```pascal
 procedure TfrmReceiver.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
    var
      sText: array[0..255] of Char;
      s: string;
      ms: TMemoryStream;
    begin
      case Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData of
        0: { Receive Text, Text empfangen}
          begin
            StrLCopy(sText, Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData,Min(Length(sText), Msg.CopyDataStruct.cbData));
            label1.Caption := sText;
          end;
         1: { Receive Image, Bild empfangen}
         {
          begin
            ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
            try
              with Msg.CopyDataStruct^ do
               ms.Write(lpdata^, cbdata);
               ms.Position := 0;
              image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
            finally
              ms.Free;
            end;
          end; }
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Please specify Delphi version. Please do some debugging. What bytes are sent, and what bytes are received?

Comment: Please edit the question to add the details that I requested.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the data as 8-bit Ansi.  However, if you are using Delphi 2009 or later (you did not say), where `String` and `Char` are Unicode, then you will have problems.

Change your Delphi code to the following, which will work in all versions:

```
procedure TfrmReceiver.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  sText: AnsiString;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  case Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData of
    0: { Receive Text, Text empfangen}
    begin
      SetString(sText, PAnsiChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData), Msg.CopyDataStruct.cbData);
      Label1.Caption := Trim(sText);
    end;
    1: { Receive Image, Bild empfangen}
    {
    begin
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        with Msg.CopyDataStruct^ do
          ms.Write(lpData^, cbData);
        ms.Position := 0;
        Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    end;
    }
  end;
end;
```

If you change your C++ code to send the actual `FileName` length and not blindly send 255 always, then you can remove the `Trim()` from the Delphi code.

Another problem with this code is that 0 and 1 are very poor choices for `dwData` values. You should use `RegisterWindowMessage()` on both sides to generate more unique values that are less likely to clash with other people's use of `WM_COPYDATA` (even the VCL uses `WM_COPYDATA` internally, for instance).  For example:

```
const UINT MyTextMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("MyTextMsg"));
// ...
if (MyTextMsg != 0)
{
    COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
    cds.dwData = MyTextMsg;
    // ...
}
```

```
var
  MyTextMsg: UINT = 0;
  MyImageMsg: UINT = 0;

procedure TfrmReceiver.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  sText: AnsiString;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  if (Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData = MyTextMsg) and (MyTextMsg <> 0) then
  begin
    // ...
  end
  else if (Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData = MyImageMsg) and (MyImageMsg <> 0) then
  begin
    // ...
  end;
end;

initialization
  MyTextMsg := RegisterWindowMessage('MyTextMsg');
  MyImageMsg := RegisterWindowMessage('MyImageMsg');
```

Also, just an optimization - if you derive a class from `TCustomMemoryStream` instead of using `TMemoryStream`, you can pass the `lpData` pointer to `TCustomMemoryStream.SetPointer()` so `LoadFromStream()` will be able to read from the message data directly and you will not have to make a separate copy of it in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have corrected the delphi code but problem is the same, I have Delphi 5, app just not recieve full string, only first byte, it appears that problem is in vstudio code

Comment: Aside from the `dwData` values you are using, there is nothing wrong with the C++ code you showed.  `UCHAR` is 1 byte in size, and you are always sending 255 bytes, so as long as `FileName` is using 8-bit string data (which presumably it is), then there is nothing to prevent Delphi from receiving the full data correctly. That is why David asked you to show the actual bytes being sent and received.

Comment: I am working on problem, still it does not work, thanks anyway, Delphi code is working properly between delphi to delphi app but vc++ to delphi does not

Comment: Did you verify that `cbData` is correct? Are you actually taking `cbData` into account when copying the `lpData` data? Does your data contain any `#0` bytes in it, such as in the second array slot? It sounds like you are doing something different than what has been shown here, so please update your question and copy/paste your real code or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are mixing unicode and ansi strings. Don't use TEXT macro in first case, use pure ansi string.
The fragment  sizeof(TEXT("Message Receiver")) - sizeof(UCHAR) will count invalid size for unicode string

Unicode string TEXT("Message Receiver") will be treaded as "M" when you read it to delphi char array, becaulse 'M' in unicode is two chars - 'M' and zero.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have modified question with exact problem, please help if you can?

Comment: Not downvoting your answer, but the `TEXT` macro is only being used in the call to `FindWindow`, as far as I can see. Since it's not being used anywhere with the data related to the `COPYDATASTRUCT`, it has no bearing on the problem here. (There is an issue with the return value of `FindWindow` not being checked, but that doesn't appear to be the problem here.)

Comment: There were several TEXT macro in the first version of the question

Comment: I have some ither projects to finish, but I will try to make this work, currently is on hold because of this first char send, whatever string i send, reciever is always recieving first charter

Comment: Problem solved, returned buffer had null terminated string #0 after each charter, thanks guys :)